# how to obtain HTML-free contents for non-div tags

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find the HTML-free content of all the tags **except** for tags inside `<div id="nav">`

For example, with the following HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <h1>Navigate!</h1>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <h2 class="structural">Main navigation</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="inside_nav">
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="/">inside_home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/">inside_About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
div = soup1.find("div", id="nav")

def match_only_non_divs(tag):
    return (tag.findParent("div").get('id') == div.get('id')) and tag.name != "div"

print div.findAll(match_only_non_divs, text=True)
```

This code should output:

```
[u'\n', u'Navigate!', u'Main navigation',
u'Home', u'About', u'\n']
```

BUT! it is actually outputting:

```
[u'\n', u'Navigate!', u'Main navigation',
u'Home', u'About', u'\n',
u'inside_home', u'inside_About', u'\n']
```

The code should not walk inside the inner div (id="inside_nav") but it is going inside that.
Please help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two alternatives for you:

```
print [t.string for t in div.findAll(match_only_non_divs)]
# [u'Navigate!', None, u'Main navigation', None, None, u'Home', None, u'About']

print [t.string for t in div.findAll(match_only_non_divs) if t.string]
# [u'Navigate!', u'Main navigation', u'Home', u'About']
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the cause of the problem, here is what doc says regarding `text` keyword:

> If you use text, then any values you give for name and the keyword arguments are ignored.

So, `findAll` is basically ignoring `match_only_non_divs` in `div.findAll(match_only_non_divs, text=True)`. You should get the text after you do the matching (as John Keyes suggested).

Comment: Thanks Avaris for the explanation :)